# How to send the instance type of a Java Object in JSON to Java Spring-Server Post request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, instanceof

I have a baseclass and three extending classes. For example:

BaseClass:

```
public BaseClass {
 int id;
}
```

```
public SubClass extends BaseClass {
 int sub1;
}
```

```
public SubClass2 extends BaseClass {
 int sub2;
}
```

Now i want to send a json file to my spring server and the server must check if it is a SubClass-type or a SubClass2-type

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody List<BaseClass> entry);
```

sending JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "sub1": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "sub2": 2
}
```

I except a List of BaseClasses but try to cast them in  the specific subclass. How can i do this? Following did not work.

```
if (abc instanceof SubClass) {
                log.info("abc is instance of SubClass");
} else if (abc instanceof SubClass2) {
                log.info("abc is instance of SubClass2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will accept `BaseClass` Spring will map your json to be compliant with only `BaseClass` ignoring all the other fields. So your check for subclasses will not work at all.

The simplest solution is to accept data as plain text and after that manually try to map it to your models using GSON or something similar like this

```
new Gson().fromJson("{
    "id": 1,
    "sub1": 1
}", SubClass.class);
```

But it is a bad way to handle this. 
Your approach need to be changed architecturally. The simplest way to do it is to introduce `data` field to you model like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
         "key": "sub1",
         "value": 1
     },
},
```

```
public Data {
 String key;
 int value
} 

public BaseClass {
 int id;
 Data data;
}
```

this way you will be able to check

```
if (abc.data.key.equals("sub1")) {
                log.info("abc is sub1");
} else if (abc.data.key.equals("sub1")) {
                log.info("abc is sub2");
}
```

This will require a bit more complex further implementation, but it will work.

Hope it helps.